# RESTful Geocoding API Nokia HERE for whole country

Tags: here-api

Trying to find addresses in Norway using the Nokia HERE RESTful Geocoding API where I search with only the street name, the API returns locations close to my position. This makes sense in most scenarios, BUT I need all streets with the search name in a wider area ( ex a county og even a country if the street name is not to common ).

How can this be achieved with this API ?

Comment: Could you share with us some sample code that you're using when querying the API?

Comment: Hi

Using the following URL :

http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?gen=7&language=NO&country=NOR&street=Vesthellinga&housenumber=20&app_id=<app id>&app_code=<app code>

I expected to get at leasy 3 adresses returned around Oslo. But nothing is returned. If I specify &city=Asker I get one of the results in this area. 
But I need to get all existing in a wider area. How can I do this ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The two options for returning geocode results within a confined area are geocode using `partial address` information:

[Partial Address - Country is critical e.g., NOR](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/latitude-longitude-by-partial-address)

and geocode an address within a `Bounding Box`:

[Bounding Box - Pass comma delimited rectangle coordinates with search text.](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/latitude-longitude-by-mapview-parameter)

The difference is in the results:

`Partial Address` with `NOR` and `Hasleveien` as the street returns 4 results while `Bounding Box` returns 5.  My experience has been that using the `bounding box` with search text versus using `partial address` with a street name will provide more results.  However, `bounding boxes` are rectangles so bounding the entire country Norway will include Sweden so you will need to filter the results to only Norway.